# alarm manager not called on samsung j and vivo

Tags: android

hey i need to send some data from my app every 15 minute and for that i am using alarm manager and calling another broadcast receiver which further hit my service.But my alarm manger is not getting called on couple of devices like vivo and samsung j due to their inbuilt security app like for xiaomi security app for samsung smart manager. Can anyone tell me What is the best approach fore time intensive background task or to solve this issue.

+here is my code

```
public class SchedulerEvent extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("APP_TAG", "schedulerevent.onReceive() called");
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, SchedulerSetupReceiver.class); // explicit
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                234324243, i, 0);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (intent != null) {
                long time = intent.getLongExtra("timing", 0);

                if (time != 0) {
                    time2 = time;
                }    
            }

            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time2, pendingIntent);
        }

        else {

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 15, pendingIntent);
        }    
    }    
}
```

My second receiver which further hit my service

```
public class SchedulerSetupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String APP_TAG = "com.hascode.android";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=19) {
            long time=System.currentTimeMillis();
            long time2=time+900000;
            Intent i=new Intent();
            i.putExtra("timing", time2);

            i.setAction("startgpsbroadcast");
            context.sendBroadcast(i);
        }

        Log.d("debug", "startgpsbroadcast");
        Log.d("APP_TAG", "SchedulerSetupReceiver.onReceive() called");
        Intent eventService = new Intent(context, SchedulerEventService.class);

        context.startService(eventService);    
    }    
}
```

Here is my service

```
public class SchedulerEventService extends BaseService {

    static GPSTracker gpstracker;
    Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    public static SchedulerEventService Current;
    MobilePhoneSignal myPhoneStateListener;
    WifiManager wifiManager;
    static Context context;
    private String batterystatus = "N.A.";

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (gpstracker.getLocationObject() == null) {
            Log.i("test", "gpsnull");
            restartGpsVariable();
        }

        hitapi();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();

        Log.d("APP_TAG", "reachedservice");
        this.Invoke(this);
        this.EnableLocalDatabase("MyyDbb0029", 29);
        getbatterystatus();

        Current = SchedulerEventService.this;
        context = getApplicationContext();
        gpstracker = new GPSTracker(context);
        // plz change db in Main Activity also//
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        myPhoneStateListener = new MobilePhoneSignal();
        TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tel.listen(myPhoneStateListener,
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private void hitapi() {
        if (isAttMarkedToday() && !isCheckoutMarked() && !checkgps()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(SchedulerEventService.this,
                    TurnGpsOnActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            SchedulerEventService.this.startActivity(i);
        }
        // else if (isAttMarkedToday() && !isCheckoutMarked()
        // && !isNetworkAvailable()) {
        // Intent i = new Intent(SchedulerEventService.this,
        // NetworkNotAvailableActivity.class);
        // i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        // | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        // SchedulerEventService.this.startActivity(i);
        // }
        if (gpstracker.getLocationObject() == null) {
            Log.i("test", "gpsnull");
            restartGpsVariable();
        }
        if (isAttMarkedToday() && !isCheckoutMarked()) {
            double latitude = gpstracker.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gpstracker.getLongitude();
            GPSWifiPropertyModel gpsWifiPrModel = loadData(
                    Double.toString(latitude), Double.toString(longitude));
            // getbatterystatus();
            if (latitude == 0.0 || longitude == 0.0) {
                gpsWifiPrModel.Latitude = null;
                gpsWifiPrModel.Longitude = null;
                gpsWifiPrModel.CheckIn_Latitude = null;
                gpsWifiPrModel.CheckIn_Longitude = null;
            }
            saveToLocalDB(gpsWifiPrModel);

            webcallTosendLocation(gpsWifiPrModel);    
        }    
    }

    protected void saveToLocalDB(GPSWifiPropertyModel gpsWifiPrModel) {
        // gpsWifiPrModel.CheckIn_Latitude = null;
        // gpsWifiPrModel.CheckIn_Longitude = null;
        // gpsWifiPrModel.Latitude = null;
        // gpsWifiPrModel.Longitude = null; Will get the last location when
        // commented
        gpsWifiPrModel.InsertOrUpdate();    
    }

    private void webcallTosendLocation(GPSWifiPropertyModel gpsWifiObj) {
        if (gpsWifiObj == null)
            return;
        ArrayList<MyInfoModel> arrMyinfoModel = getDataContextDb()
                .FetchAllData(new MyInfoModel());
        if (arrMyinfoModel == null || arrMyinfoModel.size() == 0)
            return;
        String userName = arrMyinfoModel.First().UserID;
        gpsWifiObj.UserName = userName;
        try {
            gpsWifiObj.version = Current.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    this.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        gpsWifiObj.imei = Storage.getPhoneIMEI(this);

        String gpsLocation = "UpdateMyLocation/?";
        String apiUrl = WebService.ApiUrl + gpsLocation;
        apiUrl += Encode.ToObject(gpsWifiObj);
        if (!isNetworkAvailable())
            return;
        GPSAsyTaskBackground commAsyBg = new GPSAsyTaskBackground(apiUrl,
                gpsWifiObj);
        commAsyBg.setBackgroundTask(new GPSCallBackBackgroundTask() {

            @Override
            public void callBackBackgroundTask(JSONObject jobj,
                    GPSWifiPropertyModel gpsWifiObj) {
                try {
                    if (jobj != null
                            && jobj.getString("status")
                                    .equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                        if (gpsWifiObj.isLocal.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                            gpsWifiObj.Delete();
                        updateOnServer();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        commAsyBg.execute();
    }

    private GPSWifiPropertyModel loadData(String latitude, String longitude) {
        GPSWifiPropertyModel gpsWifiPrModel = new GPSWifiPropertyModel();
        try {
            int mobileStrngth = myPhoneStateListener.signalStrengthPercent;
            int wifiStrngth = getPercentage(getWifiStrength());

            gpsWifiPrModel.networkStrngth = mobileStrngth + "";
            gpsWifiPrModel.wifiStrngth = wifiStrngth + "";
            gpsWifiPrModel.batterystatus = batterystatus;
            gpsWifiPrModel.gpsOn = checkgps() + "";
            gpsWifiPrModel.Latitude = latitude + "";
            gpsWifiPrModel.Longitude = longitude + "";
            MDAT mdat = loadTodayAttendanceFromLocal();
            if (mdat != null) {
                gpsWifiPrModel.CheckIn_Latitude = mdat.stringLatitude;
                gpsWifiPrModel.CheckIn_Longitude = mdat.stringLongitude;
            }
            gpsWifiPrModel.DeviceTime = GetCurrentDateTimeInString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ShowToast("GPSWifiPropertyModel creation exception!!");
        }
        return gpsWifiPrModel;
    }

    private int getWifiStrength() {

        int linkSpeed = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
        Log.i("test", "wifiink");
        return linkSpeed;
    }

    private int getPercentage(int wifiStrength) {
        if (wifiStrength == -200) {
            return 0;
        } else if (wifiStrength >= -100 && wifiStrength <= 0) {
            return 100 + wifiStrength;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    protected void updateOnServer() {
        ArrayList<GPSWifiPropertyModel> arrGPSWifiProp = getDataContextDb()
                .FetchAllData(new GPSWifiPropertyModel());
        webcallTosendLocation(arrGPSWifiProp.First());
    }

    public void restartGpsVariable() {
        h.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.i("test", "checkgps");
                gpstracker.stopUsingGPS();
                gpstracker.refreshGps();
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean isAttMarkedToday() {
        return isPresent(loadTodayAttendanceFromLocal());
    }

    private boolean isPresent(MDAT mdatArr) {
        if (mdatArr != null && mdatArr.option.equalsIgnoreCase("P")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private MDAT loadTodayAttendanceFromLocal() {
        ArrayList<MDAT> mdatArr = getDataContextDb().FetchAllData(new MDAT());
        if (mdatArr != null) {
            ArrayList<MDAT> mdatArr1 = mdatArr.where("ForDate",
                    GetCurrentDateInString()).where("UserName",
                    User.GetUserName());
            if (mdatArr1 != null && mdatArr1.size() > 0) {
                Log.i("test", "loadtodayattnd");
                return mdatArr1.Last();

            } else
                return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean isCheckoutMarked() {
        try {
            ArrayList<CheckoutModel> checkoutArr = getDataContextDb()
                    .FetchAllData(new CheckoutModel());
            if (checkoutArr != null) {
                ArrayList<CheckoutModel> checkoutArr1 = checkoutArr.where(
                        "ForDate", GetCurrentDateInString()).where("UserName",
                        User.GetUserName());
                if (checkoutArr1 != null && checkoutArr1.size() > 0) {
                    return true;
                } else
                    return false;
                // mdatArr.where("username", ""+User.GetUserName());
            } else
                return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public boolean checkgps() {

        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        return isGPSEnabled;
    }

    private void getbatterystatus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SchedulerEventService.this.registerReceiver(
                SchedulerEventService.this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                        Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
            int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
            // contentTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
            batterystatus = String.valueOf(level);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void RegisterTableInfoForLocalDB() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();    
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Log.d("APP_TAG", "ontasktriggered");
        // Intent intent = new Intent( this, testactivity.class );
        // intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
        // startActivity( intent );
    }
}
```

Comment: What SDK version are the two phones?

Comment: For vivo api level is 21 and for samsung is 23